# MySQL geometry type on Spark / Java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, geometry, sqldatatypes

I have a **MySQL** table and I load it on spark. The table contains a column with geometry type.
When I load the table on spark, the column with geometry type becomes with binary type in data frame.

My questions are:

- Why the geometry type in MySQL becomes binary type on spark ?
- Is there any alternative to fix that ?

I need your help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Geometry is a special data type.

Before use it, you should convert it to text or bynary.

Conversion info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html

Or you can use GeoSpark:

```java
var spatialDf = sparkSession.sql( """ |SELECT ST_GeomFromWKT(_c0) AS countyshape, _c1, _c2 |FROM rawdf """.stripMargin) spatialDf.createOrReplaceTempView("spatialdf") spatialDf.show()
```

Full tutorial below:
https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/tutorial/sql/